# Why doesn't script call the cleanup and kill the script after 5s, and I also want to get where it stoppped

Tags: bash, shell, kill, shell-trap

The script is designed to kill itself after 5s. But it doesn't kill the script after 5s, and does not call the cleanup.
The important thing is that I want to get the value of `i` when it stopped.

```
#!/bin/sh
trap "cleanup" TERM 
#call the cleanup when recive TERM
mainpid=$$
#script's pid 
cleanup()
{
    echo "cleaup called"
    echo "i=$i when it is stopped "
    exit 1
}


(sleep 5 && echo "timeout";kill -TERM $mainpid) & 
#after 5s it should kill the script 
run_test()
{
 i=1
sleep 100
i=$$(i+1)


}

run_test 2>&1 > x.log
```

Comment: Your `kill` runs in a subshell. It should be the reason. Maybe you should better use `timeout` for run_test?

Comment: I changed your sleep durations to 2 and 4: the cleanup function is called after the sleep in run_test -- that sleep does not get interrupted.

Comment: @user3132194 how could I use?

Comment: @glennjackman I think it should kill 100s then call it

Comment: @user1334609 Well, it is not as easy, as i thought `timeout 3 cat <( run_test )`

Comment: @user1334609 or `export -f run_test; timeout 3 bash -c run_test`

Comment: How to get the variable's value by cleanup when it stopped, for example for i i 'seq 100' do i=$$(i+1) done

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20565373/4934077

Answer (score 0):

Because parent processes is waiting for sleep 100 ends the "processing". If you want to process ends before sleep ends, you should kill him too.

something like

```
(sleep 5 && echo "timeout";kill -TERM `ps -ef | grep $mainpid | grep sleep |  grep -v grep| awk '{print $2}'` $mainpid) &
```